# Footnote appears on previous page, Why?

Tags: footnotes, multicol, columnbreak

My MWE part,

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,notitlepage]{report}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[turkish]{babel}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{dblfnote}

\renewcommand\thefootnote{\textcolor{red}{\arabic{footnote}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}

\lipsum

\vfill
\columnbreak

\section{\textit{Project}}
\begin{itemize}
\item W\footnote{Watt}
\item SMPS\footnote{Switch Mode Power Supply}
\item A\footnote{Ampere}
\item Footnote appears on previous page.
\end{itemize}

\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

and displaying

[image]

Where did I do wrong? How is it changing or adding in my MWE?

Comment: Please post an example code that reproduces the problem shown in the image. Without this it may be difficult for anyone to help you.

Comment: @IanThompson I'll try.

Comment: @IanThompson, I updated the my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The document produces the warning

```
Package multicol Warning: I moved some lines to the next page.
(multicol)                Footnotes on page 1 might be wrong on input line 26.
```

multicol can detect that it has happened but can not go back to fix it.

You can force a page break with the correct footnotes:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,notitlepage]{report}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[turkish]{babel}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{dblfnote}

\renewcommand\thefootnote{\textcolor{red}{\arabic{footnote}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}

\lipsum

\vfill
\end{multicols}
\clearpage
\begin{multicols}{2}
\section{\textit{Project}}
\begin{itemize}
\item W\footnote{Watt}
\item SMPS\footnote{Switch Mode Power Supply}
\item A\footnote{Ampere}
\item Footnote appears on previous page.
\end{itemize}

\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: is there a way to do this automatically? My document is very large with very big sections (typesetting a bible) and I have the same problem with the footnotes. I also had to add `\setcounter{collectmore}{5}` because of weird pagebreaks with very much free space.

Comment: @sirjofri anything is possible in theory, but with a reasonable amount of code starting from the existing code for multicol, probably not, otherwise it would reposition the footnote  rather than just making a warning. It tests for this and makes a warning as it's a known deficiency in the code but hard to change. Really it shouldn't be a problem, ignore it until the end but then check you have a clean log after final edits.